# Convert MATLAB code in Python

Tags: python, matlab, code-conversion

I have this code in MATLAB and I am trying to convert it in Python.

```
M=zeros(1,N);
i=1;
while i<=N
  ind=mod(p*(i-1)+1,N);
if ind==0
  ind=N;
end
while M(ind)~=0
  ind=ind+1;
end
M(ind)=i;
i=i+1;
ind=ind+1;
end
display(M);
M1=zeros(m,2/n_lay*n_wc);
for i=1:m
  M1(i,:)=M(2/n_lay*n_wc*(i-1)+1:2/n_lay*n_wc*i);
end
```

I don't know how to convert the for loop and what I have until now is the code below, and I don't know exactly how to convert the line "*M1(i,:) = M(2/n_lay*n_wc*(i-1)+1:2/n_lay*n_wc*i)*" here is the probleme where I get from Python "Invalid syntax".

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
N = 24
p = 2
n_lay = 2
n_wc=1
M=zeros(1,N)
i=1;
while i<=N:
    ind=mod(p*(i-1)+1,N)
if ind==0 :
    ind=N
end
while M(ind)!=0:
    ind=ind+1
end
M(ind)=i
i=i+1
ind=ind+1
end
display(M)
M1=zeros(m,2/n_lay*n_wc)
for i in range (1,m):
    M1(i,:) = M(2/n_lay*n_wc*(i-1)+1:2/n_lay*n_wc*i)
end
```

Comment: ??!?!? that code is both MATLAB and python at the same time??

Comment: Yes, I have the inital code in MatLAB, and I change all the code to python, but I have a problem with the for line.

Comment: Then you should clarify the question like "How to convert Matlab (x:y) into python". Besides, is the M1 a matrix?

Comment: Your sources of error likely are `1:2`, and parenthesis should be square brackets for index near M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of syntax errors and other mistakes in your converted code. All arrays should be converted from round brackets to square. Though this does not work, your code should look somewhat like this:

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
N = 24
p = 2
n_lay = 2
n_wc=1
M=[]
i=1;
while i<=N:
    ind=(p*(i-1)+1)%N
if ind==0 :
    ind=N

while M[ind]!=0:
    ind=ind+1

M[ind]=i
i=i+1
ind=ind+1


M1=[]
for i in range (1,M):
    M1[i,:] = M[2/n_lay*n_wc*(i-1)+1:2/n_lay*n_wc*i]
```

Also if you want to update add elements to an array, you should use "array.append(element)".

Comment: I have an error when I run this code, it is "_TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list_"

Comment: There was a problem in one of the brackets. But there is a infinite loop being created at line number 8 that you might have to fix.